# React Material UI: Make textfields stay in one row

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to make my three text fields occupy the same row always even if I resize the page. My text fields are located inside a card and I've tried to wrap the text fields with grid but no effect.

Here is my code:

```
<CardContent style={{padding: "32px"}}>
                ....
                ....
                <Grid container spacing={24}>
                    <Grid item xs={12}>
                        <TextField
                            id="re_ps"
                            label="PS"
                            value={this.state.re_pe_value}
                            onChange={this.re_ps_handleChange('value')}
                            margin="normal"
                            type="number"
                            margin = "dense"
                            variant = "filled"
                            style={{paddingRight: "20px", width: "170px"}}
                        />
                        <TextField
                            id="re_mooe"
                            label="MOOE"
                            value={this.state.re_mooe_value}
                            onChange={this.re_mooe_handleChange('value')}
                            margin="normal"
                            type="number"
                            margin = "dense"
                            variant = "filled"
                            style={{paddingRight: "20px", width: "170px"}}
                        />
                        <TextField
                            id="re_co"
                            label="CO"
                            value={this.state.re_co_value}
                            onChange={this.re_co_handleChange('value')}
                            margin="normal"
                            type="number"
                            margin = "dense"
                            variant = "filled"
                            style={{paddingRight: "20px", width: "170px"}}
                        />
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </CardContent>
```

Is it possible to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap each TextField in a Grid component and you'll get the result you want.

```
<Grid container spacing={24}>
    <Grid item xs={4}>
        <TextField
            id="re_ps"
            label="PS"
            value={this.state.re_pe_value}
            onChange={this.re_ps_handleChange('value')}
            margin="normal"
            type="number"
            margin = "dense"
            variant = "filled"
            style={{paddingRight: "20px", width: "170px"}}
        />
    </Grid>
    <Grid item xs={4}>
        <TextField
            id="re_mooe"
            label="MOOE"
            value={this.state.re_mooe_value}
            onChange={this.re_mooe_handleChange('value')}
            margin="normal"
            type="number"
            margin = "dense"
            variant = "filled"
            style={{paddingRight: "20px", width: "170px"}}
        />
    </Grid>
    <Grid item xs={4}>
        <TextField
            id="re_co"
            label="CO"
            value={this.state.re_co_value}
            onChange={this.re_co_handleChange('value')}
            margin="normal"
            type="number"
            margin = "dense"
            variant = "filled"
            style={{paddingRight: "20px", width: "170px"}}
        />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set styles for the CardContent to `{display: 'flex'}` without those Grid containers. Let the TextFields be direct children of CardContent